# decryption code for taggable friends id of facebook in ios

Tags: ios, json, facebook-graph-api, ios7, encryption

I want to post comments on friends wall. all i am doing there is accessing taggable_friends id to post on that friends wall. but for every session the friends id is getting changed. Is there any need to decrypt the id or any other possible solution. I am working on graph api, ios 7, json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`taggable_friends` does not return actual user ids, it returns tokens that you can use to tag friends in status updates etc. There is no way to convert these tokens to real user ids and is part of an effort to increase privacy.

I assume that you are using v2.0 of the Graph API, so your only option would be the `/me/friends` edge. This will return a list of all friends of the user that also use your app.
As far as I know the IDs returned there can be used to post on the timeline if you have all required permissions.

Comment: hi, me/friends does not return any value in data.. it only provides us with the total number of friends in out list. so i had to use me/taggable_friends. is there any other way through which i can tag friends in my code?

Comment: That means that none of your friends are using the app. In v2.0+ of the Graph API it returns only friends that also use your app

Comment: ok. Is there any other way to tag friends in my app? i dont want to put any restrictions of making friends use my app.

Comment: I am a bit confused right now. In your question you ask for posting to the timeline of a friend and now you ask about tagging, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: i cannot access friends wall as the id's provided by facebook are encrypted and can be used only to get information. we cannot use that id to post anything anywhere. So now i have to change it from posting on my friends wall to posting on my wall. this is why i need to tag friends

Comment: i found something to tag but have no idea about how to use it in graph api(my code). following is the link of what i have found https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#capabilities

Comment: If you want to tag a friend in a post, make a call to /me/taggable_friends, get the token for the friend you want to tag from the response (IIRC it is in the ID field) and add it to your message. For example "Hey @[THE_FRIEND_TOKEN] how are you today".

Comment: trying your solution gives me "hey, [AaLS4xsofr7P7OLU1hraUV_rntS8xYFgLbN8RXJFOMc8k5ujH3iP438k8z0xMKon89EW0Ozu0O-0CVyX7O28x9NhBNF556qhG0Vo-Z_KeAdkxA]"

Comment: Where is the @ in front of the [ ?

Comment: doing that too gives the same result. is there any other way?